# How to get selected text from dragging?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

To detect file name from file, I use code below with success.

file .h     :

```
@interface DropView : NSView <NSDraggingDestination>
```

file .m

init :

```
[self registerForDraggedTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSFilenamesPboardType]];
```

and I implement protocol like this

```
- (BOOL)performDragOperation:(id < NSDraggingInfo >)sender {

    NSLog(@"%@", [[sender draggingPasteboard] propertyListForType:NSFilenamesPboardType]);


}
```

It return Null when I dragged some text. (highlight text and dragged from other app)

I have tried to change code from 
`propertyListForType:NSFilenamesPboardType` to `propertyListForType:NSStringPboardType` or `propertyListForType:NSPasteboardTypeString`

but no luck.

Please help me how to get only selected text?

Thank you.

**I have found the solution,  Just declare NSPasteboard from sender and get string for type   NSStringPboardType**

```
NSPasteboard *pboard = [sender draggingPasteboard];
NSString *string = [pboard stringForType:NSStringPboardType];
```

Cheer!!

Comment: Does that `- (BOOL)` function return YES?

Comment: I think it's going to have the file name if you drag the actual file, not just name of it...did you try NSPasteboardTypeMultipleTextSelection ?

Comment: I have set the return to YES and have tried NSPasteboardTypeMultipleTextSelection but still null;